# ViewController Transition Trouble

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller

Here is the current code I have:

```
(IBAction)signup:(id)sender {
SignUp *signUp = [[SignUp alloc] init];
signUp.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentViewController:signUp animated:YES];
```

I am only getting an error on the bottom line. It reads: "No visible @interface for 'loginView' delcares the selector 'presentViewController:animated.'

Here is what I do not understand... I interfaced `loginView` as a child of the `UIViewController` class... This is where `presentViewController` is declared. Why is it telling me it can't find anything and how do I fix it?

Thank you ahead of time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that `presentViewController:animated:` is declared in `UIViewController`? In my docs it's listed as `presentViewController:animated:completion:`. You can have an empty completion block if you don't have anything to do there.

```
[self presentViewController:signup animated:YES completion:^(){}];
```

Comment: Or rather just pass [self presentViewController:signup animated:YES completion:nil];